# origin and uses of expression "teach one's grandmother how to suck eggs"

Tags: expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Etymology of 'teaching grandma to suck eggs'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31566/etymology-of-teaching-grandma-to-suck-eggs)

I found out about this expression that puzzles me. What is the origin and uses of the expression "teach one's grandmother how to suck eggs"?