# “Let's burn that bridge when we come to it” – is this sort of idiom mixing considered a pun, and if so, does it have a specific name?

Tags: idioms, terminology, metaphors

I couldn't come up with a short title, but the upside is that there is not much needed to be said in the body of the question!

---

For @dmr (and others), it mixes “let's cross that bridge when we come to it” and “burn one's bridges”.

Comment: I'm being a little slow here, but which two idioms is this phrase mixing?

Comment: Well, let's take a wild stab in the back!

Comment: @dmr - "We'll cross that bridge when we come to it" and "Let's not burn any bridges". I generally use this exact mashup of the two to indicate that I don't want to risk an incompetent stab at a problem until I absolutely have to.

Comment: My favorite mixed metaphors: We've got to stop spoon-feeding these people. It goes in one ear and out the other. And One man's goose is another man's gander.

Comment: @Merle - that spoon-feeding/in-one-ear thing isn't a mixed metaphor, just a badly aimed spoon.

Comment: @Steve314 ...still...if food comes out of a different ear than it goes into, that person has problems.

Comment: If we can hit that bullseye, the rest of the dominoes will fall like a house of cards. Checkmate. - [zb](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFLq7cyHKMg)

Comment: You can't choose your relatives, but you can be a beggar.

Comment: Also: Too many chiefs, and not enough soup.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Seems these are called [malaphors](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/Malaphor.htm)

> Definition:
>
> An informal term for a blend of two aphorisms, idioms, or clichés
>   (such as "That's the way the cookie bounces").
>
> Etymology:
>
> A blend of malaproprism and metaphor, coined by Lawrence Harrison in
>   the Washington Post  article "Searching for Malaphors" (Aug. 6, 1976)

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/malaphor) has **your exact example**

> Examples include "hitting the nail on the thumb", "barking
>   up the wrong alley" and "We'll burn that bridge when we come to it".

Comment: I was going to suggest [antanaclasis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antanaclasis) but "malaphor" is better.

Comment: Hum, I guess ‘Wiktionary has your exact example’ is quite a convincing argument!

Comment: @Malvolio: antanaclasis seems a different usage altogether from this case.

Comment: @F'x - assuming the person in question didn't edit Wiktionary themselves to add it :P

Comment: My favorite is "it's not rocket surgery". Also, I've hypothesized that this is the origin of ["teach your grandma to suck eggs"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31566/etymology-of-teaching-grandma-to-suck-eggs/31587#31587).

Comment: @Dusty: Yup - I edited it in way back in December 2008 precisely for this question to come along ;)

Answer (score 12):

I believe the term for this is [mixed metaphor](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/mixed-metaphors.aspx)

This is where you take two common metaphors and mix them together, often incorrectly, to make a metaphor that doesn't make sense.

For example, mixing "You can't have your cake and eat it" with "It's not over till the fat lady sings" might produce "It's not over till you've had your fat lady and eaten it".

If your particular example is meant as a joke, then I would say that it is a pun.

Comment: I agree that this is a sort of mixed metaphor, but a "mixed metaphor" is more commonly used to describe the result of *accidentally* combining two metaphors in a way that does not make sense as a whole. "For me it was stormy in the great sea of life, but then I came to a crossroads."

Comment: @Eric "...but did not want to jump without a parachute."

Comment: An excellent source of mixed metaphors is the 6-part sketches 'Peter and John' on the British TV program 'A Bit of Fry and Laurie'. The two hard-drinking Fitness club owners do a lot of damage to standard English idioms. Example: Fry:'The boardroom and the bedroom are just two sides of the same agenda'

Answer (score 2):

It's fun to use a mixed or reverse metaphor deliberately and which elicits corrections from jerks who don't get the joke. Three of my favorites are: 'If you can't laugh at other people, who can you laugh at?'; 'It's as plain as the face on your nose!'; 'I thank you from the heart of my bottom.'

Answer (score 1):

We have been calling these mixaphors here;  a portmanteau of mixed and metaphor.  We think they are the funniest thing since sliced bread.