# Does this vulgar expression necessarily imply a certain body part?

Tags: slang, offensive-language, idiom-meaning

My question is about the expression "suck on it."

Background (you can skip this paragraph if you want): at Spanish SE we were doing some back-translating of a game we were playing in Spanish.  When we were trying to find an English equivalent for "Si os molesta, tirad de esta," a possible translation as  "If it bothers you, suck on it" was proposed.  This is not an expression I'm familiar with personally.

The only [definition of **suck on it**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=suck%20on%20it) I could find is from Urban Dictionary:

> 1. that's too bad; deal with it; put up with it; tough luck; tough titty
> 2. exclamation of triumph when you want to rub someone's nose in it
>      Examples:
>      *BILL: I just missed out on first prize in the lottery by one number.
>      OWEN: Suck on it.*
>      *As you play the winning move in a game of skill or chance against others, you call out, "Suck on it!"*

Okay, the UB entry shows a functional definition and examples of how to use the expression.  But what I want to know is, when the people in the conversation say or hear the expression "suck on it," is there a specific, implied referent for "it"?

Comment: I'm sure you can guess what *it* is!

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Yes, but I'm asking if that's always implied when this idiom is used.

Comment: Probably linked in meaning and usage to: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/sit_on_it

Comment: I’m sure there are people out there who use the expression with no idea what it might refer to.

Comment: @Jim - Would you mind turning that into an answer?  I'm still confused.  The body part in question seems so blindingly obvious -- I don't understand how people might be oblivious to that (after the age of 10 or so).

Comment: @aparente001 -  Not sure that comment meets the criteria for answer.  But anecdotally, I had a friend with a young son who labelled himself a “Bad MF” on a social media platform. His mother had to explain to him what that meant.

Comment: There is a related expression "suck it and see".  "They have changed the payments system, what shall we do". Answer "Let's suck it and see".

Comment: I'm fairly certain I've several times heard usages such as "Let's suck  on that for awhile and see what we come up with", implying that the parties involved should contemplate it for awhile, as if sucking on a lollipop.

Comment: @WS2 - I don't see how that's relevant....

Comment: @HotLicks - Not sure how that's relevant....

Comment: @aparente001 Another figurative use, simply to indicate that the OP's is not a unique metaphorical use of "suck".

Comment: Related (not a duplicate) https://english.stackexchange.com/q/185777/80039

Answer (score 3):

*Suck on it!* usually implies fellatio.

But, it can be contextually clear you don't mean that.

> If your thumb bothers you, suck on it.

It can also be used to say, take that:

> I'm right and you're wrong. Suck on that!!

As in, keep that in your mouth and "enjoy" it for a while.

Comment: Well, my proposal was *Like it or lump it*.  What do you think?

Comment: @aparente001 Seems better to me.  I'm not a native speaker, though.

Comment: Hi David, just a minor correction: Spanish _"tirar de"_ would translate to "pull" in English, not "toss".

Comment: @DavidM I am from Spain. _"Tirar de [algo]"_ means "to pull [something]": _tirar de la cuerda_ → pull the rope; _tirar de la puerta_ → pull the door. The translation you are using, "to toss [something]", means "tirar [algo]" (notice: no "de") and is more akin to "to throw [something]": _tirar la pelota_ → toss the ball. You are welcome to stop by [spanish.se] to ask a question about the difference, btw; we are always looking for new people! :D

Comment: @walen I bow to your superior knowledge.

Comment: @DavidM Not sure if that was sarcasm or not, but no bowing needed, thanks. I just wanted to help :)

Comment: @walen No sarcasm. Just acknowledging that I was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>I decided to transfer what was meant as a comment into an answer because even constructive comments made *without malice* can be deleted because the author of a post can be offended by them. Political correctness runs both ways.</sub>

It's normally "sucking one's thumb" or "thumb sucking" or "(s)he sucks her/his thumb", not "suck on it".

If the burn or cut is minor, you can suggest "*try sucking on it*". But in the OP's specific situation *no one* is going to think the speaker is referring to a thumb, a finger, or any suckable part of the human anatomy that is *not* the male genitalia.

The, primarily, American English expressions, ***suck it up***, ***suck on it***,  are **supposed to be  vulgar**.

Comment: I'd never, nor have I ever, taken offense to any of your comments. You've always posted them in good faith.

Comment: Suck it up isn't really about fellatio to my mind. It's more of a suck in your gut and get going.

Comment: @DavidM I am being "general", it's endemic across SE, meta  included. In any case, even supported answers written in good faith are deleted by mods.  I am heartily fed up.

Comment: I agree that the comment mods have gotten rather stricter than 5 years ago.

Comment: Hi, Mari-Lou! I think we all agree that the expression is supposed to be vulgar -- just like many others that do _not_ refer to body parts. The question is not whether or not the expression "if you don't like it, suck on it" is vulgar, but whether or not the second "it" always refers, unequivocally and without exception, to the penis. I initially agree with @DavidM that "it" can refer to the general situation one is bothered by, but I am here to learn.

Comment: @walen if the expression *if you don't like it, suck on it* is devoid of context, it will always suggest rudeness. Whether the listener will *always* consciously think of the penis, it's impossible to say. This is true for any expression where human genitalia or sexual intercourse is normally implied, e.g. *Is it hard?* Does the word "hard" only refer to the erect penis? No, but in the context where I used it,  was it clear I was referring to that? Yes.

Comment: Suck it up is not vulgar. "Suck it up buttercup" is a common phrase used even by dad's talking to their very young children. I see your response to David that you are being "general", but I am just adding this comment to say I believe that this is inaccurate even in general. Of course, the English language is a constantly evolving thing and words and phrases take on new meaning as time goes by and different people use them. So your experience may differ from mine, but I come from a family with a VERY Christian background and no one I know would even blink at that phrase.

Comment: @BVernon A parent using that expression to their very young child is teaching them a lesson about life, and if said with a smile or with good ole "horse sense" it is meant to be jocular. But could a 12-year-old child repeat it to their teacher? I don't think so. Would you say if an employee told his boss to "suck it up", that the employer would not flinch or think anything of it?

Comment: The logic you're employing here could be equally said of many non vulgar phrases, and no dad I know would say such a phrase with vulgar intent to a child under 10. Furthermore, I looked it up and it originated with pilots who had to "suck it up" if they threw up in their helmet... which much more closely aligns with literally every context I have ever heard the phrase used than anything vulgar. So sorry, but you are just mistaken on this one!

Comment: @BVernon https://7esl.com/suck-it/ Admittedly it's without the preposition "up" but there isn't that huge a difference between "suck it" and "suck it up". But dialects vary and what one considers an innocent expression is perhaps uncouth or rude for another.

Comment: @Mari-LouA In one breath you compare the similarity of two phrases to suggest their meanings are likely similar; then you suggest the same phrase can mean completely different things to different people. I'm not arguing that either of those points are wrong when used in proper context, but it's obvious here that you are searching for reasons to support a predetermined outcome rather than reasoning to find an outcome.

Comment: The only people who would think "suck it up" has a bad connotation are those who haven't heard it used in context very often. Someone like that may then pick up on the phrase and misuse it, but that doesn't change the meaning. It doesn't commonly have a vulgar intent... only if you specifically intend it to (in the same sense that you can spell your child's name any way you want and it's not wrong; but that doesn't make it a normal spelling).

Comment: @BVernon I agree, when you tell someone to suck it up, that is not vulgar. It's pull in your stomach and get one with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fellatio notion is quite clear:

***[Suck:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/suck)***

> Meaning "do fellatio" is first recorded 1928. Slang sense of "be contemptible" first attested 1971 (the underlying notion is of fellatio).

(Etymonline)

also

***[Suck (on) this!](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/2y2fsbq#xyy4zna)***,
a dismissive or challenging exclamation:

> 1978  [US]    H. Selby Jr Requiem for a Dream (1987) 41: *[He] told it in a soft, vicious voice, Suck on this.*

(GDoS)

Comment: What about sucking on a lollipop?

Comment: @HotLicks - a euphemism?

Comment: yes, the literal implication of the penis is indeed clear.  That's not what I'm asking.  I'm asking, when one uses this expression, is the implication *necessarily* the penis?  Thanks and sorry if my question wasn't as clear as I'd have liked.

Comment: @aparente001 - you are asking  a POB question in that case.

Comment: @user067531 - "That sucks" may have had its origin in the sexual meaning, but now the phrase has come to take on a more general meaning.  I'm trying to find out if that is also the case with "Suck on it."

Comment: @aparente001 - the literal expression may be lost in time and the expression may have become a sort of set phrase, just an exclamation.

Comment: @user067531 - Well, that's what I'm asking -- whether that's the case. // I don't think "suck on this" is the same thing as "suck on it."

Comment: In support of @HotLicks' comments on this page, it should be noted that the phrase that the question is about is *suck **on** it*. In describing fellatio, *suck* is usually used without *on*, while it is often used with *on* in describing what one does with lollipops and similar confectionery, as well as what a baby does with a dummy.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that "suck on it" is related to "suck it up" which means to put up with something unpleasant. It is obscure as to its origins but there are suggestions from [wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/suck_it_up) and [the Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=suck%20it%20up) that it comes from: parade ground instructions to "suck in your stomach" when doing pressups; the expression "suck up your chest" meaning to take a deep breath and throw out your chest or from the necessity for a pilot to swallow his own vomit when he's been sick in his breathing mask.

Neither of these sources is exactly reliable and the idea that "suck on it" and "suck it up" are related is tentative but it is a possible meaning for the expression without the sexual inference.

Comment: I thought that was a good idea.  But then I asked my sixteen-year-old.  He said "suck on it" is not the same as "suck it up," and he said the penis reference is exact.  He said it's the same as "suck my d---".  I asked if young women ever say "suck it up," and he said, sometimes -- but I'm not sure how common that is.

Comment: @aparente001 As a British person I'm not too familiar with "suck on it". I was really working from the OP's original Spanish which was translated to "If it bothers you suck on it" and doesn't sound to me like a context in which anyone would say "suck my dick". I suspect that a more accurate (though perhaps less  literal) translation of "tirad de esta" would be "suck it up" rather than "suck on it". It would be interesting to have the OP's reaction. I checked the translation of "tirad" and it is, as I thought with my minimal Spanish, "pull" rather than "suck" anyway.

Comment: Walen already clarified that the English back-translation he provided was a functional, not a literal, translation; and he was aiming for an expression that would match the tone; he also clarified that in the original, the reference to the penis was clear, albeit implicit.  Let me know if you can't find that and I will look for it and give you a link.

Answer (score 1):

The formulation that the question is about is *suck **on** it*. That makes it somewhat surprising that most of those who have responded saw in it an allusion to fellatio: when the word *suck* is used to describe that act, it is usually used without *on*, or any other preposition. On the other hand, *suck on* is often used for very different activities: one sucks on a lollipop, a baby sucks on a dummy. What the activities that are typically described as sucking on something have in common is that they are relatively protracted. Lollipops and the confectionery that Americans call ‘hard candy’ are designed to release only a little bit of flavour at a time, so that consuming them is extended over a relatively long period (much longer that it would take to consume a differently made sweet of the same size). Because of that literal use for intentionally protracted activities, *suck on it* is a suitable term to use metaphorically to express something like ‘You will be stuck with this problem for a while, take your time with it, don’t expect any immediate resolution’. So used, the phrase does not carry any allusions to sexual matters, even though, needless to say, it is still highly informal.

This answer is an elaboration of the point that was originally made by Hot Licks in a couple of comments, but that hasn’t so far been engaged by any other contributors to this page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may simply reference something that you cannot enjoy by biting into it and rather something that takes time to dissolve much like the burn that is usually referenced when suck on it or this, is used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer is interesting. but we prefer answers based on facts, and not opinion,

Answer (score 0):

The vulgar referent is strongly implied, such that [proffering another object](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5c/Primus-Suck_on_This.jpg) on which to suck is still a double entendre.