# sarcastic responses as used in comedy or joking around

Tags: puns

when a supervisor gives unsolicited advice on how to do something as a reminder and you have been doing this job just that way for the last twenty years and you want to say ...really for real you are advising on that?  Do you have any puns or sarcastic sayings that you could joke around with your co workers so as not to be so offended??

Comment: Asking a question sincerely,  "Do I unscrew the cap left or right?" .  "Should I take the key out of the lock after I lock the doors ?"  might crack them up pretty good.

Comment: You could turn to your co-workers as soon as the supervisor is gone and say, "Glad X set me straight on that one. Oh, by the way, has anyone seen my head? I seem to have mislaid it." But humor of that type may not replay well if someone recounts it later to the supervisor. As Harry Shearer says, "Comedy isn't for amateurs"—and that is doubly true of comedy that implicitly criticizes the judgment of one's hierarchical superiors.

Comment: In a similar vein: "Those who can, do; those who can't—supervise!" There is also the nearly obsolete but weirdly amusing proverb "Don't teach your grandmother to suck eggs!"— discussed on this site at at [Etymology of 'teaching grandma to suck eggs'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31566/etymology-of-teaching-grandma-to-suck-eggs)—a remark that people used to make when someone advised someone else about how to do something that the advisee had been doing perfectly well for years.

Comment: What is your actual question? If all you're asking for a list of jokes, that's off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with sarcastic remarks about your supervisor because there is always a chance he or she will find out what you really think. Anyway, here are some options:

> Oh, it's so kind of him/her to teach me!
>
> How sweet of him/her!
>
> I'm so grateful for his/her helping hand!
>
> What would I do without him/her?
>
> He/she is such a help!
>
> He/she is such a lifesaver!

Please note that all of the phrases above can be used not sarcastically and mean sincere gratitude. But sarcasm is a kind of irony, and your listeners will hopefully understand that you are not that serious thanks to the note of sarcasm in your voice. So your intonation and context really matter!